# Detect Mouse Wheel Scrolling Input with Unity`s new Input System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, user-input, mousewheel

I'm currently trying to detect the mouse wheel scrolling input for my 2D Game I am currently doing in the Unity Engine.

I'm using the new Input System and I'm currently stuck with the follwing code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem.Controls;

public class ZoomController : MonoBehaviour
{

private PlayerControls playerControls;

private void Awake()
{
    playerControls = new PlayerControls();
}


private void OnEnable()
{
    playerControls.Enable();
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    playerControls.Disable();
}

void Start()
{
    
}

void Update()
{

    if (playerControls.Land.Zoom.ReadValue<Vector2>().y >= 1)
    {
        Debug.Log("Scroll 1");
    } else if (playerControls.Land.Zoom.ReadValue<Vector2>().y <= -1)
    {
        Debug.Log("Scroll 2");
    }
    
 }
}
```

[image]

If I run the code nothing happens and I don't know why.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you treat the scroll wheel as a "1D Axis" you need to tell Unity which side (up or down) should win. Otherwise, you will only receive an average value which will always be 0.

[image: Action as 1D Axis - tell Unity which side wins]

Another option that is better would be to let the value pass through and add a "Binding".
[image]

[image]

Note that the default scroll value is 120 on most systems, but on Linux it seems to be 1. I would therefore recommend simply checking if the value is larger or smaller than 0 to decide if it is scrolling up or down.

```
float z = zoom.ReadValue<float>();
if (z > 0)
    Debug.Log("Scroll UP");
else if (z < 0)
    Debug.Log("Scroll DOWN");
```

Comment: I tried your method and printed out the Value that I get from playerControls.Land.Zoom.ReadValue<Vector2>().y . It throws me an error: InvalidOperationException: Cannot read value of type 'Vector2' from control '/Mouse/scroll/y' bound to action 'Land/Zoom[/Mouse/scroll/y]' (control is a 'AxisControl' with value type 'float')

Comment: It prints 0 and if I try to scroll it throws me the error.

Comment: Note that the Mouse Wheel is 2D vector, but the y-direction is a float as well as the x-direction. If you want to read both values at the same time (as a Vector2) you have to define the action as a "2D Vector".

Comment: The option you describe as "better" works well for me :)

Answer (score 4):

Using code alone you can do this:

```cpp
    Vector2 vec = Mouse.current.scroll.ReadValue();
    scroll = vec.y
```

Comment: While this might work, its not a good approach for supporting multiple input devices, since you'd also need to check whether there is a mouse at all, and if there is a controller for example instead, you'd need to retrieve its inputs. This is exactly the type of heavy lifting the new input system does for you. A pure Action-Based solution is thus much more fitting

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following function for the mouse scroll input:

```
public float GetScroll() {
    return inputs.Player.Scroll.ReadValue<Vector2>().normalized.y;
}
```

It returns the float value 1, -1, 0.